# Erro ao carregar script uwsgi - cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, apache, django

Fiz as configurações para trabalhar Django com Apache, mas sempre dá o seguinte erro:

> cannot be loaded as Python module

Meu arquivo:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/myuser/public/site.com.br/public_html/app/')
sys.path.append('/home/myuser/public/site.com.br/public_html/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'site.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Tentei a permisão sudo chmod a+x, mesmo assim não consegui.

Comment: Resolvi, era um app que estava faltando, dessa forma estava dando esse erro.

Comment: Pode postar qual app estava dando erro, por favor? Pode ser util a outros usuários.

Comment: O problema era um modulo do Django que não estava instalado.